# Turn off display on macbook 1,1 running ubuntu server 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, macbook, power-management

I am just getting started with my own server and thought I could put my old black macbook to some use.

I installed Ubuntu server 11.10 as the only operating system and everything has been working out well so far.

As expected the brightness keys don't work and closing the laptops lid does not put it to sleep or does anything.

As I only want to access the server remotely, I want to disable the screen to save power without having to rip it off.

So far I tried using `vbetool` and `xset dpms` in all variations.

`echo $DISPLAY` yields nothing so i think this is the problem.

When trying `xset` I get the following error:

```
xset: unable to open display ""
```

Me being not a linux pro I can only guess that I somehow have to give hi access to my display. Is this a driver issue?

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old post, but after a long research I've found a solution that works for me. 
I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS on a 13" Macbook Pro Late 2011.

To list the backlight displays using this command:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

the output of this command was

```
acpi_video0  intel_backlight
```

So I assume that if you have `intel_backlight` in your output, you can use this command to change your screen brightness:

```
// Display off
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;"

// Max brightness
sudo bash -c "echo 1808 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;"
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Macbook Pro 2013 13" max brightness is 1388. Fortunately modifying the file in this way triggers some validations, so its relatively easy to find what the max will be for you by just trying a bunch of values.

Answer (score 0):

> Switch monitor off: vbetool dpms off
>
> Turn it on again (keyboard don't do it): vbetool dpms on

Get from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630758/shutdown-monitor-on-debian-server

Comment: no, as stated above stops working after a few minutes

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working" ?

Comment: Well, the commands do not turn the monitor on or off.
They do a few minutes after startup, but then they stop working. Its strange